Xampp database broken two or three times per week
Good afternoon everyone,
it happens to me often (2-3× per week), that database through Xampp (Windows) will not start. Of course I know how to repair it, but it is annoying. Everything works good, at the end of day, I'll turn it off by clicking stop button and switch off my computer. Next day the database won't run and I have to copy data from backup folder and restart it.
I analyzed mysql database and run repair tables. On table "mysql.columns_priv" it writes me:

Error aria_sort_buffer_size is too small. Current aria_sort_buffer_size: 16384 rows: 234 sort_length: 1006
Error Create index by sort failed
Info Retrying repair with keycache

If I fresh install Xampp and run on fresh database same repair, writes same. So it's look like the installation is broken maybe.
I updated my.ini and set another values. In phpmyadmin I can check in variables and see all values were saved, but repair table wrotes something similar. Currently I have set aria_sort_buffer_size = 268 435 456
Do you know how to fix it? :) Thank you for your help.

I've edited your tags because Xampp comes with MariaDB, not MySQL. These are not the same RDBMS product, nor are they compatible.

See also https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32806. @danblack any update on this?

I have been struggling with the same issue using Xampp for Windows with WordPress installed. I tried changing the sort_buffer_size, but the issue didn't disappear. I even tried reinstalling Xampp, but it didn't work.
The issue disappeared when I uninstalled the local MySQL server (not the one included in the Xampp installation). If you have a separate MySQL installation, you should try removing it from the environment variables. The MySQL server included in Xampp works perfectly after that.
Hopefully, this helps someone.
